# How do you sort using a dynamic number of sorting keys?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to sort data in VBA using multiple columns as keys, but the number of columns is not known ahead of time.

I tried using the `sheets.sort` method and using `.sortfields.add` witin a for loop, but this did not have any effect.

Here is the code used to sort the data:

```
For sh = 1 To 2
        Sheets(sh).Sort.SortFields.Clear
        For i = 1 To idSize
            Sheets(sh).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Sheets(sh).UsedRange.Columns(idList(sh)(i)) _
                , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        Next i
        With Sheets(sh).Sort
         .Header = xlYes
         .MatchCase = False
         .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
         .Apply
        End With
    Next sh
```

where `sh` iterates through the sheets in the workbook, and the numerical index of each column to be used as a key is in `idList`. For example, `idList(2)(1)` represents the index of the column from sheet 2 that should be the primary sort key.

This code results in no sorting happening at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.  It's just an example how to loop thru your sheets and columsn, you might want to change the intenal logic of sort order.

```
Dim intCols As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet

For Each sht In Sheets
    With sht

        Set rng = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion

        intCols = rng.Columns.Count

        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        For i = 1 To intCols
            .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Columns(i), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        Next

        With .Sort
            .SetRange rng
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With

Next
```

Comment: Thanks, I was actually missing the line in the WITH statement where the sorting range was set (.setRange). Your response helped me notice that.